# how to transfer certain cms pages from test server to production server in magento

Tags: magento

Is there a way to transfer certain cms pages from magento test server to magento production server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a script on deployment that will copy all CMS pages and block from staging to production.

```
mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD DATABASE cms_page cms_page_store cms_block cms_block_store | grep INSERT | sed 's/INSERT INTO/REPLACE INTO/' > cms_dump.sql
```

I then insert using

```
mysql -u -p DATABASE < cms_dump.sql
```

This works for me as I keep the database's in sync. However what I think you are trying to do is insert the difference between the table cms_page.

You might be able to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM database1.cms_page WHERE page_id NOT IN ( SELECT page_id FROM database2.cms_page);
```

This should give you all the ID's that are different, Then run a script that takes these rows and inserts into the production database.

Hope this makes sense.